# System Dependance Graph with frama-c

Tags: frama-c

I read that with frama-c, we can generate a PDG
 [which free tools can I use to generate the program dependence graph for c codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804591/which-free-tools-can-i-use-to-gnerate-the-program-dependence-graph-for-c-codes)
My question is: there is a way for it to generate a SDG (It is a set of PDG, it aims to modelize interprocedural dependences)?.
Anybody could help me or could give me tips about which tools could generate the SDG.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure that it answers your question, but Frama-C's PDG plugin does have inter-procedural information, in the form of nodes for parameters and implicit inputs (globals that are read by the callee), as well as for the returned value and output locations (globals that are written). It uses results of the From plug-in to compute dependencies.

If I understand correctly PDG's API in `Db.Pdg`, you should be able to obtain all nodes corresponding to a given call with the `Db.Pdg.find_simple_stmt_nodes` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Virgile! You are right! PDG plugin does have interprocedural information. I read the doc about the frama-C api on their website and i also played a bit with the plugin so i saw that it also constructs the SDG